# Definition of Boolean subalgebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, metalogic

I'm reading [Logic as Algebra](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/logic-as-algebra) and the definition for a Boolean subalgebra of a Boolean algebra $A$ is a subset $B$ of $A$ such that $B$, with respect to the operations of $A$, is a Boolean algebra.

This seems fair.

Immediately an example of a Boolean algebra $B$ which is a subset of a Boolean algebra $A$ such that $B$ is NOT a Boolean subalgebra of $A$ is given.  Namely, if $X$ is an arbitrary set and $A=\mathcal{P}(X)$, and $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$ then $B=\mathcal{P}(Y)$ is a subset of $A$ and is itself a Boolean algebra but not a Boolean subalgebra of $A$.  The operations are the natural ones ($1_A = X$, $0_A=\emptyset$, $\vee=\cup$, etc.).

The reason given that this is not a Boolean subalgebra is: The unit element of $A$ is $X$ which is not contained in $B$.

This seems fair.

Fast forward a few pages and we define a Boolean homomorphism (in the obvious way).  Then the first example of a B homomorphism is:

> Let $C$ be an arbitrary B alg. and let $p_0$ be an arbitrary element of $C$.  Define $D = \{p: p\le p_0\}$ (where $p\le q$ means $p\wedge q = p$).  Then let $0_D := 0_C$, $\wedge_D:=\wedge_C$, and $\vee_D := \vee_C$ but define $1_D := p_o$ and $\sim_D{p}:= p-p_0$. Then apparently $D$ is a Boolean subalgebra of $C$, and there is a natural homomorphism $\varphi:C\to D$ namely $p\mapsto p\wedge p_0$.

This seems correct too... but also appears to conflict with the counterexample given above.  If the reason $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ is not a Boolean subalgebra of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is simply that $1_A \not \in B$then it appears we are in the same problem with this boxed example since $1_C\mapsto 1_C\wedge p_0 \not \in D$ since after all $1_C \wedge p_0 = p_0$ and so it is not the case that $1\le p_0$.

> > So why is the former example not a Boolean subalgebra while the latter apparently is?

Comment: So apparently the former does not respect the operations of the ambient space but the latter does?  They seem on par with one another, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the latter example, $D$ is *not* a Boolean subalgebra of $C$.  If the text claims otherwise, it is an error.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/Logic_as_Algebra.html?id=52FJ8ht2W2AC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false

It's on page 62 -- you can preview this page on google books.  I don't believe I'm misrepresenting Halmos... and I just have a very hard time believing that Halmos could be wrong on such a simple point.

Comment: And.... yes, my intuition based on the original definition agree with what you are saying.  But, precisely, why is it the case that $D$ is not a Boolean subalgebra of $C$?

Comment: You mean the example at the start of section 28?  It never claims $\mathbf{A}$ is a subalgebra of $\mathbf{B}$...

Comment: The reason $D$ is not a Boolean subalgebra of $C$ is exactly what you wrote in the question: $1_C\not\in D$ (unless $p_0=1$).

Comment: They do not explicitly state $D$ is a Boolean subalgebra of $C$. However, it is claimed that homomorphisms send Boolean subalgebras to Boolean subalgebras.  Every Boolean algebra is trivially a Boolean subalgebra of itself so since $p\mapsto p \wedge p_0$ is a homomorphism the claim that $D$ is a Boolean subalgebra of $C$ would seem to follow. This is my question.

Comment: "Homomorphisms send Boolean subalgebras to Boolean subalgebras" means that if $C'$ is a subalgebra of $C$ and $f:C\to D$ is a homomorphism, then $f(C')$ is a subalgebra of $D$.  Here all that says is that $D$ is a subalgebra of $D$, not that $D$ is a subalgebra of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a subset of $B$, both carrying some structure, there is a difference between saying "there exists a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$" and "The inclusion map is a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$."

I guess that's what we're seeing here. If $A\subseteq B$, then there exists a boolean algebra homomorphism from $\mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathcal{P}(B)$ but the inclusion map $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$ isn't it, since the $1$ of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is not the $1$ of $\mathcal{P}(B).$

Comment: Your score is 9,999 that's really cool.... had to mention this sorry.  But I don't see where we are required to have it that the inclusion map is a homomorphism.

Comment: @Squirtle don't upvote me! I gotta keep this going!

Comment: @Squirtle it's not required that the inclusion map is a homomorphism. But in those nice cases where this occurs, we have a Boolean subalgebra. In the case of powersets, we don't have this.

Comment: So are you claiming that the definition of a Boolean subalgebra is:  $B$ is a Boolean subalgebra of $A$ if and only if the inclusion map is a Boolean homomorphism?

Comment: @Squirtle yes, that's what I'm claiming. Although I admit it's not because of  a deep seated belief in it, but rather I'm just trying to justify the positions staked out in your textbook.